# Embedding multiple stacked graphs in PyQt5 application

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt5, visualization, pyqtgraph

I am trying to display stacked graphs in a PyQt5 GUI that I've built.
[Concept of graph I am trying to replicate](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bHPZL.png)
I am trying to use pyqtgraph as it seems to work with PyQt5 but am I willing to change library if there is a better alternative.

The goal is to create a widget that displays multiple signals. Each signal's plot should be stacked on top of each other with their own y axis and share x-axis with "Linked Views".

The closest thing that I've found online is this:
https://github.com/pyqtgraph/pyqtgraph/issues/1658
Unfortunately it doesn't contain code explaining how to do it.

I am quite lost between all the PyQt5 and pyqtgraph widgets and struggling to find which one my widget should inherit from.
All ressources I find online suggest to use QtDesigner but I want to understand and be able to build these things "by hand".

I have tried creating a widget that inherits from QWidget but I'm struggling to get QGraphicsGridLayout working.

Comment: "it doesn't contain code explaining how to do it" » the very first answer to that post links a full example of 4 graphs linked in different ways (including their x-axis).